# Pygame: Simple Cosine Function

Tags: pygame, trigonometry

I'm attempting to call a simple cosine calculation. This is my code:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import math

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((480, 480))
myfont = pygame.font.SysFont("monospace", 15)
angle = 90*(math.pi/180)

while True:

    adj = math.cos(angle)
    display = myfont.render("opposite side: " + str(adj), 1, (255, 255, 0))
    screen.blit(display, (100,40))
    pygame.display.flip()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit(0)
```

Since cos(90)*5=0, I would expect the code to display that value. Instead I receive the following:

6.12323399574e-17

Comment: Pretty basic error: http://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html says for `cos` "Return the cosine of x radians."

Comment: He's converting 90 to radians with `angle = 90*(math.pi/180)`

Answer (score 0):

This will happen with [floating point arithmetic](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html). You should truncate the value before displaying it to the user.

Comment: Damn that was fast. Thanks :)